# Hilt java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException after migrating to 2.31.2-alpha

Tags: dagger-hilt

Migrating from

```
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha'
```

to

```
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.31.2-alpha'
```

Cause the below simple code

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MainApplication: Application()
```

to error with

```
:hilt:kaptDebugKotlin
[Hilt]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparent I miss migrating the `kapt` of the `hilt-android-compiler. All have to migrated together

```
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.31.2-alpha'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha03'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.31.2-alpha'
```